# Program is meant to picture a graph with vectors but output returns: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" for last plt.arrow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

this python program is meant to picture a graph with vectors but python returns this: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" for last plt.arrow(). I don't know if anyone can help me but I would be glad if someone could resolve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help !

```
# cellule 1: importation des différentes bibliothèques
from lycee import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# cellule 2: coordonnées de la position du satellite

R = 42164000          # rayon en mètre
T = 84164             # période de révolution

t = np.arange(0, 84164, 500)  # dates en secondes
a = 2*np.pi/T*t               # α=2π/T*t

x = R*np.cos(a)     # x=Rcosα
y = R*np.sin(a)     # y=Rsinα

# cellule 3: coordonnées du vecteur vitesse (vx,vy)


def coordvit(t, u):
    vu = []
    for i in range(len(u)-1):
        vui = (u[i+1]-u[i]/(t[i+1]-t[i]))
        vu.append(vui)
    return vu


vx = coordvit(x, t)
vy = coordvit(y, t)

# cellule 4: coordonnées du vecteur accélération


def coordaccelerer(vu, t):
    au = []
    for j in range(len(vu)-1):
        auj = (vu[j+1]-vu[j]/(t[j+1]-t[j]))
        au.append(auj)
    return au
    
ax = coordaccelerer(vx, t)
ay = coordaccelerer(vy, t)

# cellule 5: coordonnées du vecteur force gravitationnelle

MT = 5.972*10**24      # masse de la Terre en kg
m = 4192               # masse du satellite après avoir consommé 1000kg de carburant, en kg
G = 6.67408*10**(-11)  # consante de gravitation universelle en m^3.kg^-1.s^-2

Fx = (G*MT*m/(R**2))*(-x/R)
Fy = 0


# cellule 6: tracé du graphique (trajectoire du satellite, vecteurs accélération et force gravitationnelle)

plt.figure("acceleration et fg d'un satellite", figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(x, y, "r+-")
plt.xlabel("x en m")
plt.ylabel("y en m")
plt.xlim(-50000000, 50000000)
plt.ylim(-50000000, 50000000)
plt.title("Mouvement d'un satellite géostationnaire autour de la Terre \nComparaison des vecteurs accélération et ""force gravitationnelle")

for k in range(len(ax)):
    plt.arrow(x[k], y[k], 50*ax[k], 500*ay[k], facecolor="b", edgecolor="b", width=20000, head_width=1000000, length_includes_head=True)    # tracé vecteur accélération
    plt.arrow(x[k], y[k+1], 50*Fx[k], 500*Fy[k], facecolor="r", edgecolor="r", width=20000, head_width=1000000, length_includes_head=True)   # tracé vecteur fg
plt.show()
```

The last plt.arrow is where it doesn't work !

Response to an answer to my initial question by Green Cloak Guy:
I'm pretty sure it's the same. Here is my friend's code which runs perfectly:

```
# importation des différentes bibliothèques
from lycee import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# cellule 2 : coordonnées de la position du satellite

R = 42164000  # rayon en mètre
T = 84164  # période de révolution en seconde
t = np.arange(0, 84164, 500)
alpha = 2 * np.pi / T * t  # α=2π/T*t

x = R * np.cos(alpha)  # x=Rcosα
y = R * np.sin(alpha)  # y=Rsinα


# cellule 3 : coordonnées du vecteur vitesse (vx,vy) à l'aide de la création d'une fonction

def coordvit(t, u):
    vu = []
    for i in range(len(u) - 1):
        vui = (u[i + 1] - u[i]) / (t[i + 1] - t[i])
        vu.append(vui)
    return vu


vx = coordvit(t, x)
vy = coordvit(t, y)


# cellule 4 : Coordonnées du vecteur accélération

def coordaccelerer(vu, t):
    au = []
    for j in range(len(vu) - 1):
        auj = (vu[j + 1] - vu[j]) / (t[j + 1] - t[j])
        au.append(auj)
    return au


ax = coordaccelerer(vx, t)
ay = coordaccelerer(vy, t)

# cellule 5 : Coordonnées du vecteur force gravitationnelle

MT = 5.972 * 10 ** 24  # masse de la Terre en kg

m = 4192  # masse du satellite après avoir consommé 1000 kg de carburant

G = 6.67408 * 10 ** (-11)  # constante de gravitation universelle en m^3.kg^-1.s^-2

Fx = (G * MT * m / (R ** 2)) * (-x / R)
Fy = (G * MT * m / (R ** 2)) * (-y / R)

# cellule 6 : Tracé du graphique permettant de visualiser la trajectoire du satellite, les vecteurs accélération et
# force gravitationnelle

plt.figure("Vecteurs acceleration et fg d'un satellite de la Terre", figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(x, y, "+", label="y=f(x)")
plt.xlabel("x en m")
plt.ylabel("y en m")
plt.xlim(-50000000, 50000000)  # extrémités des échelles sur x et y
plt.ylim(-50000000, 50000000)
plt.title(
    "Mouvement d'un satellite géostationnaire autour de la Terre \nComparaison des vecteurs accélération et force "
    "gravitationnelle")

for k in range(len(ax)):
    plt.arrow(x[k], y[k], 50000000 * ax[k], 50000000 * ay[k], facecolor="b", edgecolor="b", width=200000,
              head_width=1000000, length_includes_head=True)  # Tracé du vecteur accélération
    plt.arrow(x[k], y[k], 20000 * Fx[k], 20000 * Fy[k], facecolor="r", edgecolor="r", width=200000, head_width=1000000,
              length_includes_head=True)  # Tracé du vecteur force gravitationnelle
plt.show()
```

Comment: `Fx` and `Fy` are numbers. Why are you trying to take the `k`th element of them?

Comment: Ok. However, one of my friends has typed the exact same program and weirdly it works with Fx[k] and Fy[k]. I don't really understand why !

Comment: Are you sure it's the _exact_ same program?

Comment: I'm sending you his code through an answer to my initial question 

Comment: Actually through an edit of my initial question as it is preferable.